# Add variable name to HTML Markups

Tags: javascript, html, variables, vbscript, global-variables

The VBScript below makes two files using the input from the input dialog. 
Below I would like to add the filename (`fileName`) to the `document.write('Confirm file"&filename&" completed');` in the JavaScript file created in the scripts below.

But when I do it comes back as the variable name in quotes just as written above and not the variable itself. I know it's something to do with the quotes but I am lost to what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

```
fileName=InputBox("Enter a Name for the new SubRoutine: ","Enter    Value","NewRoutine")

CreateFolder
CreateHTML
CreateJS

Sub CreateHTML
  Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set objNewFile = objFS.CreateTextFile(fileName&"\"&fileName&".html")
  objNewFile.WriteLine "<html>"
  objNewFile.WriteLine "<head>"
  objNewFile.WriteLine "<title>Created by Robot--MM</title>"
  objNewFile.WriteLine  "</head><body>"
  objNewFile.WriteLine "<script type='text/javascript'     src='"&fileName&".js'></script>"
  objNewFile.WriteLine "<script>"&fileName&"()</script>"
  objNewFile.WriteLine "</body>"
  objNewFile.WriteLine "</html>"
  objNewFile.Close
End Sub

Sub CreateJS
  Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  fileName2 = fileName & ".js"
  Set objNewFilejs = objFS.CreateTextFile(fileName&"\"&fileName&".js")
  objNewFilejs.WriteLine "var "&fileName&" = function() { window.alert('Hi,This is an alert from the file : "&fileName2&"');"
  objNewFilejs.WriteLine "document.write('Confirmed file loaded.'); }"
  objNewFilejs.Close
End Sub

Sub CreateFolder
  Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
  strPath = Wscript.ScriptFullName
  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strPath)
  strFolder = objFSO.GetParentFolderName(objFile)
  Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
  Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strFolder & "/"&fileName)
  objShell.Run objFolder
  Set Sh = Nothing 
End Sub
```

Comment: The line you're referring to (`document.write('Confirm file"&filename&" completed');`) doesn't even appear in the code you posted.

Comment: Yes because it doesn't work. "Confirm file loaded" in the 5th line of Sub CreateJS is the location I would like the line to go. Thanks .

Comment: You should edit your question to show your code exactly how it is when it _doesn't_ work.

Answer (score 0):

I have made this a simplified answer. I realized I had the quotes in the wrong place. Here is the solution with a few upgrades.

```
    fileName = InputBox("Please enter a name for your new files:", _"Create File")
    US =                CreateObject("WScript.Shell").ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%UserProfile%")

   Sub CreateHTML
    Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objNewFile = objFS.CreateTextFile(US &"\Desktop\"& fileName&".html")
    objNewFile.WriteLine "<html>"
    objNewFile.WriteLine"<link rel = 'stylesheet' href='"&fileName&".css'>"
    objNewFile.WriteLine "<head>"
    objNewFile.WriteLine "<title>Created by Robot--MM</title>"
    objNewFile.WriteLine  "</head><body>"
    objNewFile.WriteLine "<script type='text/javascript'       src='"&fileName&".js'></script>"
    objNewFile.WriteLine "<script> "&fileName&"()""</script>"
    objNewFile.WriteLine "</body>"
    objNewFile.WriteLine "</html>"
    objNewFile.Close
    End Sub



    CreateHTML 


    Sub CreateJS
    Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objNewFilejs = objFS.CreateTextFile(US &"\Desktop\"& fileName&".js")
    objNewFilejs.WriteLine "window.alert('Hi,This is an alert from the file ');"
    objNewFilejs.WriteLine "document.write('Document loaded')"
    objNewFilejs.Close
    End Sub


    CreateJS


    Sub CreateCSS
    Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objNewFileCSS = objFS.CreateTextFile(US &"\Desktop\"& fileName&".css")
    objNewFilecss.WriteLine "body {text-align:center;font-family:'Zapfino',serif;}"
    objNewFilecss.Close
    End Sub

    CreateCSS
```